# HashMap Values Becoming Invalid?

Tags: java, networking, hashmap

So, I wrote this function which gets a list of users and their locations (it's a mobile phone app), it sticks the correct values into the hashmap (ret.put(...)) but once the function returns, all the values in the map have been set to an incorrect UserID of 0 and Location of 0,0.  It seems to me that Java is deleting fmsg, which is then deleting the UserID and Location I've placed in the map.  What do you guys think?

```
public HashMap<UserID, Location> getFriendsLocations(ArrayList<UserID> friends) {
        MessageHdr hdr = new MessageHdr(sock);
        hdr.len = 2;
        hdr.id = MessageID.FRIENDS.id;
            //Transmit the list of users' we are interested in
        for(UserID u : friends) {
            if(!hdr.send() || !u.send())
                return null;            
        }
            //Now, start receiving responses from the server.
        HashMap<UserID, Location> ret = new HashMap<UserID, Location>();
        FriendsMsg fmsg = new FriendsMsg(sock);
        for(int i = 0; i < friends.size(); i++) {
            if(fmsg.recv())
                ret.put(fmsg.uid, fmsg.loc);
        }   
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: My mistake was reusing the same object for each Friend; and not defining myself the getHash and equals functions.  The reason I got UserID's and Locations of 0's was that FriendMsg resets itself during every call to recv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your `UserID` is mutable, and changes in a way changing its hashCode and/or equals behavior. This way you blow the `HashMap` completely.

Answer (score 1):

Don't blame it on Java. What you show here doesn't say what the structure
or usage of UserID or Location are.   fmsg.recv() is probably reusing the
structure that represents them (just as you are reusing the FriendsMsg structure)

Comment: It is as a matter of fact, so I suppose I should just move the declaration of fmsg into the loop?  And I was only hypothesizing xD

Comment: that might or might not change the result.  you have to know what fmsg.recv() does.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to say what is wrong with your code because the code snippet that you gave is incomplete. We don't have much information about your data structure(FriendMsg,ArrayList friends, etc ) and the data received from the server. Just to tell you, the error will not come Java or the HashMap. You have to make sure that you are receiving the correct data.